# Count leading zeros between the decimal point and first nonzero digit

Tags: r, regex, desctools

Suppose if we have a number 1.000633, I want to count number of zeros after the decimal point until first nonzero digit in the fraction, the answer should be 3. For 0.002 the answer should be 2.

There is no such function in R that could help. I have explored at Ndec function in package DescTools but it does not do the job.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using `regexpr` and its `match.length` argument

```
attr(regexpr("(?<=\\.)0+", x, perl = TRUE), "match.length")
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I didn't think about the possible options where it went wrong.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Annie see edit, I used `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr` in order to avoid `sapply`. Now it is fully vectorized and much faster.

Comment: For `x <- 10.2` this returns -1 instead of 0. I had to insert an `ifelse` statement in my solution to capture a case where it would fail without it. This might be a reason why you consider my implementation complicated. On the other hand, maybe you could consider capturing such cases, too, so that your solution also works for any number.

Comment: @RHertel it always returns `-1` for no match. That is the `regexpr` notation for no match. My solution works for *any* number.

Comment: Alright, I understand that - just as I understood why my original post needed a correction. I'm just not sure if this corresponds to the OP's requested output ("..count number of zeros after the decimal point until first nonzero digit..."). A negative count of zeroes does not seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: @RHertel this can be easily fixed in a vectorized way if OP desired, but in this case -1 or 0 seems to be equally fine to me to for no match.

Comment: Fair enough. After all, the OP decides.

Comment: @RHertel Simply using `(?<=\\.)0+|$` as the regex should do if you want to get 0 instead of -1.

Comment: `attr(regexpr("(?<=\\.)0+", 0.0001, perl = TRUE), "match.length")` returns `-1` instead of `3`. That's not supposed to happen, is it?

Answer (score 16):

Here's another possibility:

```
zeros_after_period <- function(x) {
if (isTRUE(all.equal(round(x),x))) return (0) # y would be -Inf for integer values
y <- log10(abs(x)-floor(abs(x)))   
ifelse(isTRUE(all.equal(round(y),y)), -y-1, -ceiling(y))} # corrects case ending with ..01
```

Example:

```
x <- c(1.000633, 0.002, -10.01, 7.00010001, 62.01)
sapply(x,zeros_after_period)
#[1] 3 2 1 3 1
```

Comment: @zx8754 better now..?

Comment: I liked this solution even with 0.001 issue.

Comment: I think you forgot to vectorize it as now it only work on a length one vector only... Myabe this should be `ifelse(round(y) == y, -y-1, -ceiling(y))` ?

Comment: Not columns, just several values, such as `x <- c(0.1, 1.0, 1.001)`

Comment: I wonder why I have two comments below my answer with the content "it doesn't work". As matter of fact, it does work.

Comment: Not sure why are you being so aggressive. My second comment was regarding my previous comment. I was trying to help you vectorize it. Not sure what the point to write such a complicated implementation if this only meant for one value.

Comment: It is easy to misinterpret things in writing. If you read carefully what I posted, I don't think you'll find something aggressive. And if you do, it was not my intention. Now, emotions aside, concerning your criticism that this answer is complicated: it may be in the eye of the beholder whether a mathematical expression is more complicated than some regex formulas. I prefer maths, especially when the object under consideration is a number. It is a function that spans two lines. Complicated? I don't think so.

Comment: `y = log10(abs(x) %% 1)` also seems to work. To make it vectorized, `y = -log10(abs(x) %% 1); ceiling(y) - ( (y %% 1) < 10^-options()$digits )` or using some other threshold, I guess. There is probably still an edge case or two

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553244/count-leading-zeros-between-the-decimal-point-and-first-nonzero-digit/35553571#comment58831988_35559346

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the link to your comment. That answer certainly deserves an upvote.

Comment: You can increase the number of detectable digits using this solution by altering the default value of tolerate in all.equal() to, for example, .Machine$double.eps

Answer (score 9):

We can use `sub`

```
ifelse(grepl("\\.0", str1), 
    nchar(sub("[^\\.]+\\.(0+)[^0]+.*", "\\1", str1)), NA)
#[1] 3 2 3 3 2
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
r1 <- stri_extract(str1, regex="(?<=\\.)0+")
ifelse(is.na(r1), NA, nchar(r1))
#[1] 3 2 3 3 2
```

Just to check if it works with any strange cases

```
str2 <- "0.00A-Z"
nchar(sub("[^\\.]+\\.(0+)[^0]+.*", "\\1", str2))
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
str1 <- as.character(c(1.000633, 0.002, 0.000633,
                                  10.000633, 3.0069006))
```

Comment: @Annie Can you please check it again.  Based on the example I posted, it is not counting

Comment: Thanks again, try with str1 <- as.character(10.000633).

Comment: BTW, 

library(stringi)
nchar(stri_extract(str1, regex="(?<=\\.)0+"))

This works like a magic :). Thanks much.

Comment: You probably need to edit your first solution as it is wrong.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Yes, I forgot about `+`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I am gettiing 3 as the result

Comment: @akrun there could be any number there, and this should work for all numbers. Almost everyone have a comment under their answers with possible issues, not just you. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553244/count-leading-zeros-between-the-decimal-point-and-first-nonzero-digit/35553571#comment58794809_35553373) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553244/count-leading-zeros-between-the-decimal-point-and-first-nonzero-digit/35553571#comment58795433_35553441) for instance

Comment: What do you mean with: *"Okay, Jaap is also online"*?

Comment: just allow for digits apart from 0 in ther rest of number, like `"[^\\.]+\\.(0+)[^0]{1}.*"` and it'll be find (though I'll still prefer the `numeric` approach of RHertel). It's a matter of accurate solution, not of upvote

Comment: @Jaap It means `you are online`.  Did I say anything bad?

Comment: No, I just found it to be an odd statement in a comment addressing @Cath

Comment: You should do the same with the `stringi` solution as it also counts `NA`s as two characters... Sorry for being annoying :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  In your solution, it returns `-1`

Comment: Yes, when there is no match it gives -1

Answer (score 7):

Using `rle` function:

```
#test values
x <- c(0.000633,0.003,0.1,0.001,0.00633044,10.25,111.00012,-0.02)

#result
sapply(x, function(i){
  myNum <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(i), ".", fixed = TRUE))[2]
  myNumRle <- rle(unlist(strsplit(myNum, "")))
  if(myNumRle$values[1] == 0) myNumRle$lengths[1] else 0
})

#output
# [1] 3 2 0 2 2 0 3 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way using `str_count` from `stringr` package,

```
 x <- as.character(1.000633)
 str_count(gsub(".*[.]","",x), "0")
 #[1] 3
```

EDIT: This counts all zeros after decimal and until first non-zero value.

```
y <- c(1.00215, 1.010001, 50.000809058, 0.1)
str_count(gsub(".*[.]","",gsub("(?:(0+))[1-9].*","\\1",as.character(y))),"0")
#[1] 2 1 3 0
```

Comment: wow. This question escalated quickly! :). I went with the two cases mentioned by OP. I will revise asap. Thanks @DavidArenburg

Comment: What about y <- 0.00001 ?

Answer (score 6):

```
floor( -log10( eps + abs(x) - floor( abs( x ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for answering this question. Because code with no comments tends not to be very educational, we'd like you to add some explanation of how this answers the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution here. However, you should account for integer log values like this:  `count0 <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5) {
  x <- abs(x);
  y <- -log10(x - floor(x));
  floor(y) - (y %% 1 < tol)
}`

Comment: great answer, I love how it's the more mathematical approach and not all grep, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that all above solutions I tried had issues with numbers such as 0.00001 which format into scientific notation unless you are careful to specify that they don't. I ended on the following solution:

```
leading_zero <- function(x)  {
  if (x < 0.001){
    x <- as.character(format(x,scientific=FALSE))
  }
  nlead <- attr(regexpr("(?<=\\.)0+|$", x, perl = TRUE), "match.length") # leading zeros
  nlead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` since we do not need to jump. Thus no need of `gsub`

```
 nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*","\\1",str1))
[1] 3 2 3 3 2
```

where

```
str1 <- as.character(c(1.000633, 0.002, 0.000633,
                   10.000633, 3.0069006))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @MatthewPeter solution. If you use the `ceiling()` rather than the `floor()` function and then subtract 1 you do not face issues with 1*10**x numbers such as (0.1, 0.01, 0.001, ...).

```
x |>                  # input vector of numeric values
  abs() %%            # take the absolute value (delete sign of numbers)
  1 |>                # do numbers modulo 1 
                      # (delete everything before the decimal point)
  log10() |>          # use log10 to count the numbers after the period
  abs() |>            # flip sign, as we want the positive numbers
  ceiling() -         # take the ceiling of the numbers. 
                      # this will solve the 1*10**x issue
  1                   # substract 1 since we actually
                      # wanted the floor of the values
```

Data:

```
x <- c(0.000633,0.003,0.1,0.001,0.00633044,10.25,111.00012,-0.02)
# [1] 3 2 0 2 2 0 3 1
```